# angularjs data organisation service vs Scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Data case:**
100 different  **meals**, with all there own origin (country), preparation time, difficulty etcetera).

the two **active views**  (next to each other);

1. filter (by country, preparation time, difficulty ...)
2. List (meals which meet the filter criteria)

-What are the advantages of putting all the meals in a meal**Service** with respect to putting them directly on the scope?

**filtered list**

- should I have an object inside the `mealservice` which holds the filters (e.g. `filters={'country':'germamy', 'maxPrepTime':50}`
- should I have an object inside the `mealservice` which holds the selected meals, if for 
  example an country is added to the `searchcriterea` this list is directly updated (in the view only `ng-repeat` will be required for this list)
- should I define my own filter (`ng-repeat="meal in meals" | customFilter "`)
- other method?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a best practice you should always have [**fat models and thin controllers**](http://www.slideshare.net/damiansromek/thin-controllers-fat-models-proper-code-structure-for-mvc).

One of the most important arguments to make so is, that it will be much easier to reuse
your code if it's encapsulated in a service/factory then if it's implemented in the controller.

You can also implement you own filter, but it can actually use a method from the service.

Comment: So, I should use a service and invoke methods on that service. How should I manage my filtered list, should I call a service function with the filter arguments set in the view (on the scope) and let the filter function return the associated meals?